# IMAP IDLE and parralel mail processing

Tags: ruby, multithreading, parallel-processing, imap

I'm new both to IMAP and multi-thread programming, and I'd like to write a script to fetch incoming mails and process them in parallel.
`Thread`, `Queue`, `Mutex` and `Monitor` are new concepts to me, I may miss-use them in the following question and example.

The script's goal is to:

1. receive IDLE notifications from the IMAP server when a new mail arrives
2. fetch the corresponding mail
3. parse its body
4. generate a PDF from parsed data
5. send the report through SMTP

Another aproach could be to fetch and identify mails based on their UID, thought learning IMAP & multi-thread programing is another goal.

---

Here's what I've got so far (IMAP part):

```rb
def self.idle(imap)
  @imap = Net::IMAP.new 'mail.company.org', 143, false # Not using TLS for test purposes
  @imap.login 'username', 'password'

  @idler_listener = Thread.new do
    loop do
      begin
        imap.examine 'INBOX'

        imap.idle do |res|
          if res.kind_of?(Net::IMAP::UntaggedResponse) and res.name == 'EXISTS'
            imap.idle_done
            Thread.new { process_email(imap) }
          end
        end

      rescue => e
        puts e.inspect
      end
    end
  end.join
end

def self.process_email(imap)
  begin
    uid  = imap.uid_search(['SUBJECT', 'MyFavoriteSubject']).last
    mail = imap.uid_fetch(uid, 'BODY[TEXT]')[0].attr['BODY[TEXT]']
    puts mail
  rescue => e
    puts e.inspect
  end
end
```

This example successfully prints out the body of an incoming mail. However, if several mail arrives at the same time, only one will be treated.

---

**Q**:

- Is this behavior due to the fact that the loop is executed in a single thread ?
- Does it illustrate the need for a queue, a thread pool, or a producer / consumer pattern ?
- Chances that this script will attempt to access the same resource at the same time are low, however, would `Mutex.new.synchronize` protect me against race conditions & deadlocks ?

(Eventhough I've not fully understand it, I think it's worth sharing this great resource from Masatoshi Seki: https://www.druby.org/sidruby/)

Comment: Are you sure your library is actually thread safe?  Many are not.   But also, when you get an EXISTS notifcation that there are new emails, you only process the .last one, rather than all of them.  If they arrive simultaenously, you’ve just skipped several.  Also, an IMAP connection cannot both be monitoring emails in IDLE and fetching emails, so there’s not a lot of utility for spawning off a separate thread to fetch the email.  You *could* use a separate thread to parse and deal with the email once you’ve fetched it, but the IMAP connection itself is not really a multi-threaded entity.

Comment: The behaviour is due to that you call `.last`. Of course you process only the last. It does not illustrate the need for anything much, you can run something like `uids = imap.uid_search(['SUBJECT','MyFavoriteSubject']); mail = imap.uid_fetch(uids, 'BODY[TEXT]')[0].attr['BODY[TEXT]'] unless uids.empty?` without any queue or pool. IMAP has a single-threaded leaning, as Max says.

Comment: @Max: IDK, Ruby' IMAP is using `synchronize` but I'm not sure it's referencing the same Mutex object (I'm expecting `mutex = Mutex.new; mutex.synchronize`, instead of `synchronize`). Thanks a lot for the critics & advice, indeed fetching emails on a separate thread doesn't make much sense.

@arnt, thanks for the correction, I'm working on it and will post some code once I've got satisfying results